# How to check if a generic type instance is 'inherited' from another one, both generic type and the argument type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I'd like to check something like below:

```
  List<string> lst=new List<string>();
if(lst ?? is "Inherited" from "IEnumerable<object>" ??)
```

I mean checking whether both the 'wrapper' class and the argument class are inherited from the given classes.

Any suggest will be appreciated!

Comment: In my case, i'd like to check if the type List implements IEnumerable while at the same time the type string is inherited from object, as an instance of type List<string> is the target waiting to be checked and the type of IEnumerable<object> is the given condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean. You can check whether it's *assignable* to a type very easily:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
if (list is IEnumerable<object>) // True for .NET 4, false for earlier versions
{
    ...
}
```

In this case we're relying on the generic covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`. Not all interfaces support that, and classes certainly don't.

If you could give us more indication of the bigger picture - what you're trying to achieve - that would really help.